# Call web view from another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIWebView` on the main `UIViewController` which works fine. I use this command to send data and again it's all good:

```
[self.dWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: myString];
```

The problem is that I added another `UIViewController` (`QRViewController`) that reads data from a QR tag and I want to send it the same way.
This is my code at the `QRViewController` but nothing happens:

```
ViewController* _viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[_viewController.dWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: qrString];
```

Is it possible to do it this way? Is there something missing?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add NSString * str object to your ViewController

pass it as:  _viewController.str = qrString;

[self.dWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: self.str];

This will work

Comment: Thanks, I tried it too. I dismiss the QRViewController with [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; and I expect viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear on the main ViewController will be called to send the string but they're not.

Comment: have you tried writting your code in block ?
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

       [self.dWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: myString];

    }];

Comment: Else make a delegate to back pass data. It will surely work

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a second instance of the same `UIViewController` class by calling this code:

```
ViewController* _viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

`_viewController` is not pointing to the one visible on the screen, it is a new copy that is not currently being displayed.

You need to get a handle on the previous instance currently being displayed and pass the data back to it. This will depend on how you constructed this app.

For example:

- If present modally, you will need to get the `self.presentingViewController`.
- If you are using a navigationController you could access its `viewControllers` property to get a handle on the one before.